# Media player apps do not react to media keys when they lose the focus

Tags: windows, media-player

You may noticed that Windows Media Player will react to keyboards media keys even when its windows does not have focus. But other media player software that I have tested (PotPlayer,KMplayer) do not response to media keys when they lose the focus.

1. Is there any hack to force them to response to media keys?
2. Is there any other media player that behave similar to WMP?

Comment: I don't use pot player or km player but I know for Winamp I had to go and enable "use global media keys" (or something similarly named, I'm away from my pc at the moment). Maybe there's something similar in km player?

Comment: @Kryten Thanks. I found simlar option in POT player. Thanks. ◕‿◕

Comment: Happy to help :) I'll add it as answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PotPlayer, go to Preferences > General > Keyboard. There you can find the relevant settings under Multimedia Keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use pot player or km player but I know for Winamp I had to go and enable "use global media keys".

You need to find the relevant option in the program settings.

Comment: Sometime other apps like Google Play will take over these keys when installed. You may also need to disable that functionality in Google Chrome Settings